# Grails - ReloadException: Unexpected exception occuring while running grails application

Tags: grails

I am getting this unexpected exception while running application on grails. I have done `clean, compile and run-app` many times but nothing happens. It cleans and compiled successfully but when I do `run-app` this exception occurs:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Reloading agent exited via exception, please raise a jira
    at org.springsource.loaded.agent.ClassPreProcessorAgentAdapter.transform(ClassPreProcessorAgentAdapter.java:110)
    at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:188)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:428)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.ResolverUtil.addIfMatching(ResolverUtil.java:390)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.ResolverUtil.loadImplementationsInDirectory(ResolverUtil.java:292)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.ResolverUtil.loadImplementationsInDirectory(ResolverUtil.java:290)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.ResolverUtil.loadImplementationsInDirectory(ResolverUtil.java:290)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.ResolverUtil.findInPackage(ResolverUtil.java:204)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginRegistry.loadFromPackage(PluginRegistry.java:222)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginManager.collectPlugins(PluginManager.java:152)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:144)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:361)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:426)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:442)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:138)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:147)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:41)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:175)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:426)
    at com.asklytics.provisioning.TenantProvisioningManagerService.<clinit>(TenantProvisioningManagerService.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrConstructorNewInstance(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1075)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
    at org.grails.spring.beans.factory.OptimizedAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.instantiate(OptimizedAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:89)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1098)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1050)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireByName(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1244)
    at org.grails.spring.beans.factory.OptimizedAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireByName(OptimizedAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireByName(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1244)
    at org.grails.spring.beans.factory.OptimizedAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireByName(OptimizedAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:51)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:335)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:324)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at analyticsapplication.Application.main(Application.groovy:8)
Caused by: org.springsource.loaded.ReloadException: Problem defining class com..analytic.services.ELBService$_stub_closure1__I
    at org.springsource.loaded.TypeRegistry.defineClass(TypeRegistry.java:1306)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ReloadableType.rewriteCallSitesAndDefine(ReloadableType.java:939)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ReloadableType.<init>(ReloadableType.java:173)
    at org.springsource.loaded.TypeRegistry.addType(TypeRegistry.java:1104)
    at org.springsource.loaded.agent.SpringLoadedPreProcessor.preProcess(SpringLoadedPreProcessor.java:335)
    at org.springsource.loaded.agent.ClassPreProcessorAgentAdapter.transform(ClassPreProcessorAgentAdapter.java:107)
    ... 79 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor50.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springsource.loaded.TypeRegistry.defineClass(TypeRegistry.java:1298)
    ... 84 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com//analytic/services/ELBService$_stub_closure1__I (wrong name: com/analytic/services/ELBService$_stub_closure1__I)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:642)
    ... 88 more
```

I am not sure why the name of class is ending with `$_stub_clouser1__I`? Any one please help me out.

[image]

Comment: My last-ditch effort to fix weird runtime errors is to go to my user directory (~ or c:\users\<username), find the .grails directory, delete the cache's there, then clean & compile again.   This has fixed several issues for me over the years, especially when I'm bouncing between applications with different versions of grails.

Comment: Which Grails version? Could you list files in your grails-app/services directory?

Comment: @Michal_Szulc its `3.0.10` edited my question listing directory

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, looks like you might have a bad package declaration in your file:

check the "package" line in the file ELBService.groovy

it might have an extra period in there: com..analytic.services

Comment: maybe search your entire project for "com..analytic", perhaps a controller you're injecting into is importing using that?

Answer (score 0):

Problem probably is connected with TenantProvisioningManagerService.java line 35. Please check it out.

Moreover did you try to update Grails for example to 3.0.16? Did you check also package naming in tests files with injected service?